# IIS http to https rewrite rule and exclude IP address

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I wrote a http to https rewrite rule in IIS. 
I want to exclude a http://XXX.XX.XXX.XX (one single IP address) from this. 
Then I want to write another rule that rewrites those http://XXX.XX.XXX.XX and https://XXX.XX.XXX.XX to https://www.foo.com (my domain which I have ssl certificate for).

Here both rules:

```
<rule name="http to https redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/XXX.XX.XXX.XX$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Redirect to my site">
                <match url="XXX.XXX.XXX.XX" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="XXX.XXX.XXX.XX" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https:www.foo.com" />
            </rule>
```

It does not work with the excluded pattern and I wonder if the second rule applies at all. Any advise is wellcome.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules FRT can easily show you what's up with your rules (and what mistakes you might make).

Comment: Did you try to change theaction type in the second rule from Rewrite to Redirect?